# Are there any native (Microsoft) API for Windows Explorer FTP (under Windows XP) for access login credentials?

Tags: windows, ftp, explorer

REWORK FOR REOPEN:

How can I have access to Windows Explorer FTP programmatically via command line or PowerShell or VBScript? THNX

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I have been using Windows Explorer as an FTP.
I accidently clicked Save Password when logging in meaning that it automatically logins me into that account when I connect to that specific server.
How can I remove those saved credentials?
Cheers

Comment: That's a question for Super User (http://superuser.com/) I think.

Comment: Thanks David, I wasn't aware of that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open User Accounts by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking User Accounts and Family Safety (or clicking User Accounts, if you are connected to a network domain), and then click User Accounts.

In the left pane, click References.

Click the password that you want to remove, and then click Remove.